# Show ViewController on different Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have 3 storyboards for 3 different device screen size. I want to move from the main ViewController to the second ViewController when a button is pressed for the 3 storyboards. Here's the code:

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 1136){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
    else {
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
  }

  return YES;
}
```

The code to move to second ViewController:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone/Main_iPhone4/Main_iPad" bundle: nil];
ArcadeView *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"arcade"];
self.window.rootViewController = svc;
```

However, when i use the above code. XCode tells me

> "Could not find a storyboard named
>   'Main_iPhone/Main_iPhone4/Main_iPad' in bundle NSBundle.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Why are u creating 3 storyboards ? you can use autolayout . check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: The error itself clearly states about the issue.

Comment: do you have storyboard with name 'Main_iPhone/Main_iPhone4/Main_iPad" ?

Comment: @Kalpesh I'm also doing for pre iOS7

Comment: @HuyNghia Yes, i have storyboards with those names

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a storyboard with name @"Main_iPhone/Main_iPhone4/Main_iPad".

To make it work the way you want, do better in every storyboard make identical transitions and sign them the same identifier. 
And for the transitions, use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMainMenu" sender:self]
```

But in general, I advise you to learn more about constraints. So it will be much easier

Comment: If i use Main_iPhone, Main_iPhone4 and Main_iPad separately, it works? For example:                                                  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];             UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone4" bundle: nil];              UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle: nil];

Comment: But you shall think 100 times before you do so. The fact that 99.999% of problems can be easily solved with a storyboard. So either you have a very very specific task, or you do not correctly use the tools available.

Comment: Do you have a better way to combine the different storyboards in one line?

Comment: NO no, I mean make resize interface in one storyboard.